# How to debug todonotes issues (expandafter {\@captype)

Tags: errors, revtex, debugging, todonotes

In a LaTeX document (using `revtex-4.2` and `todonotes`), I run into issues with to-do note related errors – which seem erratic and which I somehow cannot debug. The issue seems to be related to a certain number of `todonotos`, somewhere around 40, but here's the wider story:

Compiling the document with pdflatex (14159265-2.6-1.40.20, TeX Live 2019) I get the following error

```
./document.tex:441: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...tally@float \expandafter {\@captype 
                                                  }
l.441    not?}
              closer to the cation the Coulomb attraction grows and results ...

./document.tex:441: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \ftype@ 
l.441    not?}
              closer to the cation the Coulomb attraction grows and results ...

./document.tex:441: Extra \endcsname.
\tally@float ...ame ftype@#1\endcsname \endcsname 
                                                  \@ifnotrelax \@tempa {\@if...l.441    not?}
              closer to the cation the Coulomb attraction grows and results ...
```

Commenting out either the first or the second half to the text (or any good chunk of the document) this works without error as long as the overall number of todo notes is <~40. That is, no single todo note or any other code of the document causes the error as such, only in the sum the errors occur.

However, creating a minimal example I see that todo notes as such has no problem with 100 notes:

```
\pdfoutput=1
%\documentclass[galley]{revtex4-2}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage{forloop}
\begin{document}
\noindent Testing the number of todonotes without error \\
\newcounter{ct}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 101}%
{%
   \noindent testing \todo{Note \thect}note \thect. \par
}
\end{document}
```

If I choose the revtex4-2 document class instead of article in the example above, I get some other error (which I assume to be an revtex4-2 vs. forloop incompatibility)

```
./minimal.tex:13: Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles.
<argument> ...do {Note \thect }note \thect . \par 
                                                  \addtocounter {ct}{1}\forl...l.13 }
```

Now, is there a known issue here?
What could be the actual problem with my original document?
How could I go ahead and investigate this systematically?

Let me point out that I see this same behavior repeatedly when I add a significant numbers of todo notes to a revtex document.

Comment: I don't know `revtex` nor `todonotes`, but the “Undefined control sequence: `\@captype`” error could happen as a result of using `\caption` outside any  `figure` or `table` environment. As for the `Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles`, this suggests that something is retaining contents, delaying its shipping out via the `\output` routine. Maybe you need to add normal text to allow the retained material to find a place? (just a humble guess since I don't know these packages)

Comment: Unrelated: why are you setting `\pdfoutput=1`?

Comment: It is not related to `todonotes` but to the fact that `todonotes` uses `\marginpar` internally, you get the same error with just `\marginpar{test}`. I tend to use the `fixme` package instead of `todonotes`. Fixme can be configured to use the `marginnote` package and then does not rely on the `\marginpar` command.

Comment: @daleif Thank you for the suggestion. I did switch our groups macro package to fixme now, which is a bit of a pain for everybody (which is the reason I did not go that route previous times I arrived at todonotes problems... thank you for the reminder;-) But now its set to layout `pdfcnote`:-O `layout=marginnote`, also with `innerlayout=inline`/or similar does not really provide useful output – horizontal alignment does not work on all pages, notes overlap each other, etc... But that's for another day and question;-) **fixme** it is now:-)

Comment: The price of marginnote is the overlap, but that can be manually adjusted by adding an extra option to fxnote. I neven have a setup that also add the marker path used by todo

Comment: @daleif, the `\pdfoutput=1` is there to force use of PDFLaTeX, e.g., when my emacs config or arXiv  just run `latex` as a command – because I do want PDF output and because the included graphics are also PDFs...

Comment: Emacs has its local variables and I'm quite sure you can tell arxiv to use pdflatex, you should no longer rely on that setting

Comment: Is there anything bad about the `\pdfoutput`?

Comment: Is your `todonotes` mimicking setup something the average coworker can handle? Would you mind sharing it as an answer to the original question?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar problem with `todonotes` and `revtex-4.2`, where after a certain number of notes the `Undefined control sequence` `captype`-related error appears (similar to the OP, no one *specific* note is triggering it).

Putting this invasive-looking `\def\` in the preamble solves the problem:

```
\makeatletter \def\@captype{figure} \makeatother
```

without any side-effect obvious to me. Maybe it helps in debugging the issue to work out a better fix.